# jqPlot Bar Graph Not Rendering Correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqplot

I'm trying to get started using jqPlot in my jQuery Mobile app, but I can't seem to get one of the examples on the jqPlot site to work. My code:

```
var s1 = [2, 6, 7, 10];
var s2 = [7, 5, 3, 2];
var ticks = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

$.jqplot('chartdiv', [s1, s2], {
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        pointLabels: { show: true }
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            ticks: ticks
        }
    }
});
```

should produce this graph:

[image: Correct grpah]

Instead, I get this:

[image: What I'm seeing]

Notice the x-axis labels all rendered on top of each other in the bottom-left corner. What could be causing the chart to render wrong?

Comment: Yes, the jquery.jqplot.css file is included and loaded on the page.

Comment: Is the chartdiv initially hidden when populating the plot

Comment: No, chartdiv is always visible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I struggled with the same problem. After some testing I found out that I actually hadn't included the category axis renderer plugin.

So if you still have the same trouble try including it. (plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js)

Answer (score 0):

Another reason this might happen is if you add the scripts to your HTML file in the wrong order. Note that the jquery has to be included first, then jqplot, and finally any plugins.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the references to jqPlot scripts were placed inside of the head-block. After replacing them to the body-block the problem was solved.